# Bulk Discount on quantity based by percentage

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I am using standard **Configurable** and **simple product.**
I want to add bulk discount for all users on  matching products Only .
I can't do it from catalog product tier price rule  option because i have a large  catalog so i can't Do it manually   in every product.My condition is. 
 if **Quantity of products  is 7 to 24 discount = 5%** 
and if **qty of products equal to and greeter than 25 discount should be 10%**.
Thanks in Advance.